# Can't make a div child opaque with opacity property

Tags: html, css

I'm making a popup that when showing up, blurs the rest of the page in grey, `.cover` is taking care of the page overlay. However, I can't overwrite it's `opacity:0.6;` rule with !important. I want the inner `<div>` to become opaque and the parent to be transparent.

HTML:

```
    <div id="cover">
        <div id="popup">
            <img src="EFTI_POPOVER2.png" alt="endurance films institute" id="pop-img">
            <button id="pop-but" onclick="location.href='http://endurancefilmsti.com/sales/'">
                <span id="#but-span">
                    <strong>YES!</strong>
                </span>SHOW ME THE FUTURE OF ENDURANCE SPORTS TRAINING</button>
            <a id="back" href="#">No Thanks, Continue Shopping</a>
            <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#cover{ 
    position:fixed; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); 
    z-index:5; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    display:none; 
    opacity:0.6;
} 
#pop-img {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: won't work with a wrapping div, anything within the div cannot override that opacity.. you need the overlay to be under

Comment: So, I swaped their positions and boosted the z-index of the image, and it's still covered under the overlay.

Comment: Do you need `opacity` at all? `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);` will make the background of `#cover` semi-transparent and would have no influence on the child elements.

Comment: Already did that, it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.cover` must be closed before. If you set the opacity to `0.6`, the child nodes will have the same opacity. Increase the `#popup` z-index to get the result that you want.

```
<div id="cover"></div>
<div id="popup">
    <img src="EFTI_POPOVER2.png" alt="endurance films institute" id="pop-img">
    <button id="pop-but" onclick="location.href='http://endurancefilmsti.com/sales/'">
        <span id="#but-span">
            <strong>YES!</strong>
        </span>SHOW ME THE FUTURE OF ENDURANCE SPORTS TRAINING</button>
    <a id="back" href="#">No Thanks, Continue Shopping</a>
    <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By specification opacity is applied to the whole element including all children.

Here is pseudo code. For that element with opacity < 1.0

1. create bitmap buffer.
2. render content of the element to the bitmap.
3. blend that bitmap to the destination with the given opacity.

As you may see opacity is applied at the end.

Comment: Getting a background color of #cover with alpha channel did the job well.

Comment: @nosille in addition to this, i believe you are misunderstanding the `!important` rule. it doesn't tell the browser to override property inheritance, it merely maximises the css specificity of the selector (i.e. if two selectors target the same element with conflicting rules, the rule with `!important` will always win).